# Access RethinkDB database from LAN

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I have 3 machines connected via LAN. I want to create RethinkDB database in one machine and access it from the other two machines via LAN. I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 in a virtual machine in which I have created the database, and I am running Windows 10 and using Python in the two machines from which I want to access the database.

Comment: I know literally nothing about this topic, but I'm duty-bound to ask anyways: Can we see the code you've got so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this question is more about server configuration and networking than programming it may be more appropriate for https://serverfault.com/questions which is another site in the stack exchange family of sites.

Comment: I was not able to connect RethinkDB database from Ubuntu server to Windows Machines, so instead of running Ubuntu Server I ran Windows 10 on it, So it connected easily.

Comment: There is still an issue that the database disconnects and connects itself repeatedly.